# c++ hold reference to template instance without knowing its arguments

Tags: c++, templates

)

i am wondering how i can create a reference or pointer to a templated class
of which i do not know the concrete template argument types.

e.g. i have

```
vector<int>   a;
vector<float> b;
```

now i would like to be able to create a variable (in this case c) that can hold either a reference to a or b or any other specialization of vector, for example like:

```
vector<>& c; // <- generic reference to all specializations of class vector<T>
c = a;
cout << c.size() << endl;

c = b;
cout << c.size() << endl;
```

i am aware of the fact that it would not be possible to call push_back or any other operations that take or return arguments that are of the templated type, but i just want to call methods like size() etc. that do not require knowledge about the concrete template arguments.

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: 1. Type is required to instantiate a template. 2. Unlike pointers, references can't be reseated. They have to be initialized at point of declaration.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that this is a solution?

Comment: Could `boost::any` be the answer? You can check for type of the contained object, then make a suitable `boost::any_cast`, then call a suitable `size()` method.

Comment: Note that any unprotected pointer or reference may be left in a dangling state.

Comment: @user1095108: Slightly better than that would be using boost variant, that way you don't need to know the exact type as the visitor can itself be templated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That cannot be done. A template is the source from which the compiler will generate multiple *unrelated* types. If you want to create generic code, you could potentially:

- use type erasure for this, although it might not be worth the effort
- or you can write templates that will match the different
  specializations of the template (which will themselves generate
  different functions, but you won't have to write each one)
- or if you are in control of the template, you can use inheritance from a base
  type and move the common functions (those present in all
  specializations and for which the signature does not change) to the base

Comment: Does my answer actually answer the question he is asking, it's a little unclear

Comment: @aaronman: I don't think so. I understood that he wants to create a reference to one container that can only contain A's or a container that can only contain B's. Your solution provides the ability to mix A's and B's into a single container. (In this case I am using 'A' and 'B' as unrelated types)

Comment: Thank you! The last option, providing a basic interface, was also what i thought about - although this wont work for the stl classes.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is runtime polymorphism. Independently of using templates or not, in C++, this can only be done via inheritance and virtual methods.

Hence your only option is to create a base interface, then create a templated class that inherits the base class. All your specialized classes then share the same inherited class, from which you can call the virtual functions.

Unfortunately, you can't use this method if you are not in control of the templated class, such as `vector`, so there is no way you can do this in this case, unless building a new class that provides the common behaviour and perform casting under the hood (type erasure is a boost templated way to do that "automatically", but I'd rather write the class myself in my specific case).

My post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159494/run-time-polymorphic-class-with-value-semantics) may interest you.