# Value semantics with wrapper around polymorphic class: how to avoid copying to const-ref

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

I've got a common abstract superclass `Base`, with a variety of `Derived` classes. For convenience, I'd like to be able to operate on the base class as a value, rather than via pointers. I can achieve this by creating a `Wrapper` using the technique described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159494/run-time-polymorphic-class-with-value-semantics/17159495#17159495). The `Wrapper` stores a `unique_ptr<Base>` and forwards method calls to that pointer, and has appropriate constructors allowing me to do

```
Derived derived;
Wrapper wrap = derived;
wrap.callMethodOnDerived();
```

so the user can pass, return, and store `Wrapper` without thinking about the underlying pointers. `Base` remains entirely hidden.

However, this ends up creating copies when they don't need to be. I.e

```
void fun(const Wrapper&);

fun(derived);                  // makes copy
const Wrapper& view = derived; // makes copy
```

will call the `Wrapper(const Derived&)` converting constructor, then passes a reference to that. Instead, I'd like it to create a `const Wrapper&` which points to the original object, with no copy being made. How can I do this?

```
#include <memory>

using BigVal = int; // Could be some expensive-to-copy type
using namespace std;

struct Base{
    Base(BigVal x) : value(x){
    }

    unique_ptr<Base> clone() const{
        return make_unique<Base>(value);
    }

    BigVal getValue() const{
        return value;
    }
protected:
    BigVal value;
};

struct Derived : public Base{
    Derived(BigVal x) : Base(x){
    }
};

struct Wrapper{
    unique_ptr<Base> ptr_;

    BigVal getValue() const{
        return ptr_->getValue();
    }

    // Ignore missing copy/move assignment operators
    Wrapper(const Wrapper& other){ 
        ptr_ = other.ptr_->clone();
    }

    Wrapper(Wrapper&& other){ 
        ptr_ = move(other.ptr_);
    }

    Wrapper(const Base& other){
        ptr_ = other.clone();
    }  

    Wrapper(Base&& other){
        ptr_ = make_unique<Base>(std::move(other));
    } 
};

void constFun(const Wrapper& t){
    cout<<"Const fun "<<t.getValue()<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Base b1(1);
    Base b2(2);
    Derived d1(3);

    Wrapper w = d1; // copies

    Wrapper w2 = move(w); // moves
    Wrapper w3 = move(b1); // moves

    // No copy, just taking a reference:
    const Wrapper& w4 = w2; 
    constFun(w2);

    // Can I avoid a copy here?
    const Wrapper& w5 = b2;
    constFun(b2); 
}
```

I've attempted to fiddle with converting constructors of the form

```
Base::operator const Wrapper& (){ 
  // return 'view' on this object
}
```

But that results in ambiguity when doing `Wrapper w = Derived();`

Another option could be to make `Wrapper` never make copies unless you call `clone`, or lazily make copies when it changes. Yet another would be an independent `WrapperView` class which would be used in place of `const Wrapper&`.  But is there a way to make copies happen normally during assignment, but not when creating a reference? If not, what are the pros/cons of the other possibilities?

Comment: you can always pass by reference without any copy. what's the problem?

Comment: @appleapple If a function takes a parameter of type `const Wrapper&`, I can pass a `Wrapper` without copy; but if I pass a `Derived` or `Base`, the implicit converting constructor is called to turn it into a `Wrapper` first.

Comment: A wrapper is a value semantics polymorphic `Base`.  You are mad if you want it to be a sometimes value sometimes view based on some random set of heuristics.  A `Wrapper const&` and a `WrapperView<Base const>` are not the same thing, and wanting them to be the same is going to cause you lots of pain.

Comment: @Yakk Sure, maybe that's the wrong approach here. I'm just trying to figure out if there's a sane and self-consistent way to make polymophic value types work. With my original approach there's no way to accept a polymorphic value with consistent copy behavior, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Joe why not just use `Base&`? no need for `Wrapper` at all

Comment: @joe Sure, but if you are working with polymorphic value types, stop using `Derived` *in the same code base*.  `Derived` is an implementation detail.  If you want a wrapper around an also exposed polymorphic vtable based type, you need to distinguish between views and value type wrappers, as they are fundamentally different.  `WrapperDerived:WrapperBase`, use something like an `any` to store the value (in `WrapperBase`), `WrapperDerived` knows that it actually has a `Derived` (implementation detail).  No client code ever creates a `Base` or `Derived` directly.

Comment: @Yakk The user needs to be able to create and operate on the `Derived` types as well.

Yeah, I suppose I could make a full parallel Wrapper hierarchy that would work here. One downside could be the amount of boilerplate: if somebody wants to add a `Derived` subclass, they need to write a `Wrapper` which forwards every function call and constructor to the underlying type. Any way to avoid that?

Also... can you elaborate on the benefit of `any` here? Why not just store a pointer to `Base` in `WrapperBase` and downcast it to `Derived` in each `WrapperDerived`?

Comment: @joe the usual -- SBO etc.  Why heap allocate if you don't need to?  But sure, you could store a value ptr to Base.